# Crear un diccionario con subdiccionarios como valores

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Necesito ayuda con este código. Necesito que el output me lo de como el ejemplo pero en cambio recibo esto:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Giancito/Downloads/tabla_posicionesCamilo (1).py', wdir='C:/Users/Giancito/Downloads')

'Equipo': '"Banfield          "', 'pj': 23, 'pg': 6, 'pe': 8, 'pp': 9, 'gf': 19, 'gc': 23, 'dg': -4
```

**Enunciado**

DADO EL ARCHIVO "tabla_posiciones.csv" CREAR UN DICCIONARIO CON LOS EQUIPOS COMO CLAVE Y LOS DATOS COMO OTRO DICCIONARIO ANIDADO CON PJ, PG, PE, PP, GF, GC, DG.

**Ejemplo**

```
d = "Boca de Junin": "pj":10, "pg":10, "pe":10, "pp":10, "gf":10, "gc":10, "dg":10
```

LUEGO GENERAR UN INDICE SOBRE EL DICCIONARIO CON LOS RESULTADOS DEL  CAMPEONATO 1°,2°.... sorted....

CALCULO PARA EL ORDENAMIENTO ES: puntos pg = 3, pe = 1, pp = 0.
Por puntajes iguales, calcular dg.

```
def crear_lista(nombre_archivo):
lista = []

#"equipo","pj","pg","pe","pp","gf","gc","dg"
archivo = open(RUTA,"r",encoding = "utf8")
titulos = archivo.readline().replace("",'').replace('\n','').split(',')
linea = archivo.readline()

while linea!= "":
    linea = linea.replace("",'').split(',')
    lista.append({'Equipo':linea[0].replace("",''),'pj':int(linea[1]),'pg':int(linea[2]),'pe':int(linea[3]),'pp':int(linea[4]),'gf':int(linea[5]),'gc':int(linea[6]),'dg':int(linea[7])})
    linea = archivo.readline()

return  lista

def main():
 


lista = crear_lista(RUTA+"tabla_posiciones.csv")

print(lista[1])



 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, estaría bueno que revisaras [Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta se entienda mejor y sea bien recibida. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Hola @Gianmarco, podrías incluir un pequeño ejemplo de la estructura de tu fichero de entrada?.